# Datatables: how to preserve id when sorting through a relation from another table (yajra, laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm using datatables from [yajra datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) and I have a problem.

I have a datatable where I obtain certain columns from other tables, for example the column "customer" is obtained through a relation from another table

[image]

But when I press the sort by customer button, the IDs change to the ID of the table where the relation belongs

[image]

This generates errors in the buttons that I have on the right since these IDs do not exist in the "meos" table, only in the "locations" table that is in the relation

How can I make it sort while keeping the same ID it had?

I want to always keep as order criteria the ID of the table I am with, which is the "meos" table belonging to the "meo" class

This is my query

```
public function query()
{
    $languageId = Auth::user()->language_id;
    return Meo::with(['businessType' => function ($query) use ($languageId) {
        $query->with(['businessTypeDescriptions' => function ($subQuery) use ($languageId) {
            $subQuery->where('language_id', '=', $languageId);
        }]);
    }])->with('location');
}
```

this is my function getcolumns

```
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        Column::make('id')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.id')),
        Column::make('location.location_name')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.customer')),
        Column::make('businessType')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.business_type'))->searchable(false),
        Column::computed('action')->exportable(false)->printable(false)->width(160)->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.actions')),

    ];

}
```

please, I need help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. Add `->select()` statement

```php
public function query()
{
    $languageId = Auth::user()->language_id;
    return Meo::with(['businessType' => function ($query) use ($languageId) {
        $query->with(['businessTypeDescriptions' => function ($subQuery) use ($languageId) {
            $subQuery->where('language_id', '=', $languageId);
        }]);
    }])->with('location')->select('meo-table.*');
}
```

Replace `meo-table` with your database table for Meo::class

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this "->select" only select columns inside the location table

Comment: i have used yajra datatable with relations and if i sort by relation column i get error most of the time because the ID becomes ambiguous for the datatable.
using the select statement solves the problem for me.

Comment: ok, I added a "-> select ('id');" but now i get another error "trying to get property" businessTypeDescriptions' of non-object ", and if I remove it it works again

Comment: you needed to add your main `tablename.*`
Example

`User::with('posts')->select('users.*')`